# how celery_always_eager=True works?

Tags: django, celery

in celery doc it says `all tasks will be executed **locally** by blocking until....` what does locally mean here. Does it run the task using the workers of the main server where app is running or it sends the task directly to celery worker running remotely
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/4.0/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_always_eager

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means `Celery` will not schedule tasks to run as it would regularly do, via sending a message to the broker. Instead, it will run it inside the process that is *calling* the task (via `.apply_async()` or `.delay()`). I think this setting is applicable only in testing, so your tests do not have to run *`Celery workers`*, for example.

Comment: It seems that the configuration `task_always_eager` don't work when calling the task with `send_task`. This is in the `send_task` source code:
```warnings.warn(AlwaysEagerIgnored('task_always_eager has no effect on send_task', ...)
```
Celery 5.2.3